# Django invalidate template cache by signal

Tags: python, django, templates, caching, invalidation

In Django template I have compound cache key variable:

```
{% with video.id|to_str as video_id  %}
    {% with 'cm'|add:"video"|add:video_id as tmpl_key %}
        {% cache 3600 * 24 tmpl_key %}
            {% include 'comments/index.html' with obj=video %}
        {% endcache %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

This block caches comments on the video page.

On signal (occures when new comment was added) I'm trying to invalidate cache like this:

```
@receiver(comment_was_posted)
def comment_was_posted_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    comment = kwargs['comment']
    cache_key = "cm" + str(comment.content_type) + str(comment.object_pk)
    key = make_template_fragment_key(cache_key)
    print(cache.get(key)) 
    cache.delete(key)
```

`print(cache.get(key))` - Always returns `None` (cache invalidation fails, because there is no any cache by retrieved `key`), but I'm sure that caching works well and `tmpl_key === cache_key` are equal.

Am I doing something wrong with `make_template_fragment_key`?

Comment: What's your cache settings in settings.py ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to set "compound cache key" as concatenated string. Django template engine treats next symbol following the time section as "cache key" string.

In my question it was symbol "*":

```
{% cache 3600 * 24 tmpl_key %}
    {% include 'comments/index.html' with obj=video %}
{% endcache %}
```

So, django treats '*' as cache key and '24', 'tmpl_key' as vary_on parameters.

---

**Correct code:**

You need to pass cache params like this:

```
{% cache 3600 video_comments video.id %}
    {% include 'comments/index.html' with obj=video %}
{% endcache %}
```

And then invalidate cache by passing list of `vary_on` parameters in `make_template_fragment_key`

```
@receiver(comment_was_posted)
def comment_was_posted_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    comment = kwargs['comment']

    if str(comment.content_type) == "video":
        key = make_template_fragment_key('video_comments', [comment.object_pk])
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any errors in your code but you can improve and simplify it.
First of all `make_template_fragment_key` has `vary_on` argument exactly for dynamic params so you don't have to create cache key manually.

So you will get smth like this in your template:

```
{% cache 86400 cm video_content_type.id video.id %}
    {% include 'comments/index.html' with obj=video %}
{% endcache %}
```

... and in python:

```
@receiver(comment_was_posted)
def comment_was_posted_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    comment = kwargs['comment']
    key = make_template_fragment_key('cm', vary_on=(comment.content_type.id, comment.object_pk))
    cache.delete(key)
```

The only change is that you need to additionally pass video content_type id to your template (or at least hardcode it) because using content_type name is not a good idea.

PS. Also! I can't check it now but I'm not sure that it's legal to use math expressions like you've done so I've replaced it with simple number of seconds.